# Is it possible to see the pubkeys that pair with private keys inside the TPM in Windows?

Tags: trusted-computing, webauthn, fido2

Is it possible to inspect data (pubkeys, domain names used for webauthn, **not private keys**) related to private keys stored in the TPM on Windows?

- I legally own the hardware and have maximum permissions on my user account
- I have the necessary credentials to authenticate with FIDO2
- I don't need to see private keys (I understand [the private keys stay on the secure enclave](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/always-encrypted-enclaves?view=sql-server-ver16) and just sign items when asked). Knowing the public keys would be interesting to me.

I am asking purely for academic reasons.

If you're interested: specifically I'm interested in whether an app that uses a public asymmetric cryptosystem stores the private key in the TPM, or (what I suspect) the app generates a new keypair, and then uses the new public key to encrypt data (including the previous private key) and stored encrypted data outside the TPM, so that access to the secure enclave is needed to decrypt the stored private key.

Comment: The best start is possibly this superuser answer: https://superuser.com/a/1731263/149822

Comment: Thanks Bruno! I've run `certutil -store -silent -user My` to look through my user's personal store and can't find certs issued via webauthn.

Comment: I'm not sure where Windows stores Webauthn keypairs, but there was another SU thread about *deleting* them, and IIRC it still involved certutil but used a different store. (The `My` store holds whole certificates, but Webauthn only deals in raw keypairs. Other tools that only use the KSP to generate a raw keypair without an associated certificate aren't going to show up there, either.)

Comment: It is *very* unlikely that the key would be stored in the TPM itself though, due to limited space as well as due to Windows throwing away the "owner hierarchy" password after initialization, but I'll need to review this once I'm not on a bus

Comment: Yep @user1686 I saw your point about the limited storage in the TPM itself, and how TPM is more used as store for the key used to unlock OS secret storage, in your other answer. It was very helpful.

Comment: @user1686 Got it. https://superuser.com/questions/1527685/how-to-remove-webauthn-credentials-from-onboard-tpm-on-win10-device `certutil -csp NGC -key`

Comment: One another thing, though: I'm very much doubting that Windows' Webauthn support actually uses the TPM. It might be doing so opportunistically when possible, but... I know it works on machines that only have a TPM1 chip (which just doesn't do ECDSA, all it supports is RSA) and even on machines that don't have a TPM at all. So I believe those are *always* just "software" keys. (And in any case, your side only needs to store so-called "resident" keys; traditional Webauthn has the storage of encrypted keys offloaded to webapps themselves in a similar fashion to how a TPM does it.)